# dotplot_diag for cooks distance (lmer model) - subject value instead of index

Tags: r, plot, diagnostics, lmer

I'm using the tools in the HLMdiag package to look at diagnostics for a model fitted by `lmer`. I have a question about the `dotplot_diag` function for plotting cooks distances.

Here's an example of what I'm doing.

```
mod <- lmer(distance~age+Sex+(1|Subject), data=Orthodont)

cooksd <- cooks.distance(mod, group = "Subject")

dotplot_diag(x = cooksd, cutoff = "internal", name = "cooks.distance") + ylab("Cook's distance") + xlab("ID")
```

I get the following plot:
[image]

**Question**:  Is there a way to have influential points labelled with their `Subject` value instead of their index? i.e., it would show something like M13 or F10 (values in the `Subject` variable, see below).

```
head(unique(Orthodont$Subject))
[1] M01 M02 M03 M04 M05 M06
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `index` argument will work:

```
dotplot_diag(x = cooksd, index=levels(Subject), 
 data=Orthodont, cutoff = "internal", name = "cooks.distance") + 
 ylab("Cook's distance") + xlab("ID")
```

Comment: I had tried that (sorry, I should have mentioned it) but it doesn't work: `Error in levels(Subject) : object 'Subject' not found`. The output of the `cooks.distance` function doesn't seem to "store" the `Subject` value, but just their index, which makes it less convenient to then go back and refit a model without a few particular subjects. I imagine a solution would be to include `Subject` information in `cooksd` but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: did you remember the `data=Orthodont` argument?

Comment: It works great, thank you! I feel silly for not paying closer attention.